# Is specialist/specification question about weather data on topic?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

I have a specialist/specification question that related the geography but more like earth science or weather data namely whether darkness falls quicker in the spring / summer since it appears so where I live, that when days are longer the dusk and dawn also appear somewhat longer. Would this question be on or off-topic, if it's off-topic, can you suggest where I can ask it?

Comment: API's for Weather are good for GIS-SE but for spec see whubers answer

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest looking first at the [physics site](http://physics.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative you can try [biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question would be closed as off-topic there.